# How to format timesince filter to print hours as h in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am using Django *timesince* filter. So when I write,

```
{{ this_article.date_modified | timesince}} ago (UTC+00:00)
```

> It gives output like: `3 hours, 35 minutes ago (UTC+00:00)`

I want to ignore the **hours** and **minutes** words and just keep as simple as **hrs** and **mins**

> Expected Output: `3 hrs, 35 mins ago (UTC+00:00)`

---

I can do it by hard coding but does Django provide any filter or something like this by default?

If yes, any help is highly Appeciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source for `timesince` is located under `bin/lib/pythonx.x/site-packages/django/utils/timesince.py` It's short and should require no great effort, to modify it. Just update the `TIME_STRINGS` dictionary.

**Example:**

Update

`'hour': ngettext_lazy('%d hour', '%d hours'),`

to

`'hour': ngettext_lazy('%d hr', '%d hrs'),`